# While upgrading ES to version 5.6.16 throws error plugin [repository-s3] is incompatible with version [5.6.16]; was designed for version [5.2.0]

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, amazon-s3

While upgrading ES to version `5.6.16`, did a system restart for the new version to take effort.

Tried to get ES version, for which it said **connection refused**.

Then when I manually start elastic search throws error

`plugin [repository-s3] is incompatible with version [5.6.16]; was designed for version [5.2.0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is that I uninstalled the repository-s3
Then reinstalled it. Then I manually started the ES and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This repository plugin is used for snapshot/restore solution. To run it please upgrade plugin also to 5.6.16 version

```
sudo ./elasticsearch-plugin install -b  file:///pathToPluginZipFile/repository-s3-5.6.16.zip
```

Comment: This might work. Not tried. Yes repository-s3 is used for the snapshots. Thanks for the help.